# How can I store a JSON output in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, apache-pig

I'm using Apache Pig to run a Job on binary files. The job result is a valid JSON for example:

```
{
   "filename": "hello_world.exe", 
   "strings": 
    [
       "!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.", 
       "LRich", 
       ".text"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to use the Pig "STORE" command to save this result/json-output directly to MongoDB?

Update (Pig Script):

```
register 'my.jar';

%default INPUT 'myfile.bla'
%default OUTPUT 'generic_text.out'

data = load '$INPUT' using myloader('myScript.py');
STORE data INTO '$OUTPUT';
```

The json output (see above) from my job  is stored in the variable *data*. At the moment, my Pig script is writing the output to the file *generic_text.out*. Instead of saving into a file, I want to store the result into an existing MongoDB collection.

Comment: http://hortonworks.com/blog/pig-as-connector-part-one-pig-mongodb-and-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Till the point i am getting you is that you want to store this JSON directly into mongodb collection as a new document. Well i can say that you can iterate over the JSON keys and insert the fields by loop OR you can do another way by stringify the JSON and insert this JSON at some key, say `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoimport is utility tool for importing json data into mongodb.

Please refer the following url consisting of documentation of mongo import

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: How can I use this within my Pig Script?